Переключение между листбоксами WPF
Возникла проблема. У меня есть 2 листбокса, один выше другого. Нижний как бы скрыт, но его содержимое немного видно. а верхний полностью раскрыт.
Каким способом можно сделать так, чтобы при нажатии кнопки, нижний листбокс как бы увеличивался в высоту, затмевая верхний.
прикладываю скриншоты, как я это вижу.
Когда выбран первый листбокс:

Когда Выбран второй листбокс:

Тоесть, когда я нажимаю на кнопку, соответствующий ей листбокс раскрывается в определенную сторону, в зависимости от того, где этот листбокс находится(сверху или снизу).
Заранее спасибо!

Это зовется "Аккордеон" (пример с WEB для понимания). В WPF делается при помощи Expander, которые размещены друг под другом. Ну а дальше уже нужная логика, хотите по кнопке открыть нужный - привязывайте тогда IsExpanded, а по клику ищите нужный объект и задавайте нужное значение привязанному IsExpanded.

@EvgeniyZ Спасибо!
